# pkg 'make' error while installing package in GNU - Octave

Tags: linux, terminal, package, gnu-make, gnu

I am experiencing an error while installing a package named control in GNU Octave using forge command.

```
error: pkg: error running 'make' for the control package.
error: called from
     configure_make at line 110 column 9
     install at line 196 column 7
     pkg at line 568 column 9
```

I tried manually installation also but no successful results. Can anyone guide what's the problem? I am using octave version 6.2.0

**Edit**

```
    warning: LFLAGS is deprecated and will be removed in a future 
    version of Octave, use LDFLAGS instead
    sh: line 1: gfortran: command not found
    make: *** [Makefile:35: slicotlibrary.a] Error 127
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    make: Entering directory '/tmp/oct-i08hVt/control-3.2.0/src'
    tar -xzf slicot.tar.gz
    /usr/bin/mkoctfile-6.2.0 -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations  __control_helper_functions__.cc
    mkdir sltmp
    mv slicot/src/*.f ./sltmp
    mv slicot/src_aux/*.f ./sltmp
    cp TG04BX.fortran ./sltmp/TG04BX.f
    cp TB01ZD.fortran ./sltmp/TB01ZD.f
    cd sltmp; /usr/bin/mkoctfile-6.2.0 -c *.f
    make: Leaving directory '/tmp/oct-i08hVt/control-3.2.0/src'
```

Comment: Are there any other error messages, before those?  Do you have the `make` program installed on your system (can you run `make --version` for example)?  There's no enough information here about what might be wrong.

Comment: @MadScientist  `make` version is 4.3.  Error before those are something like this: `warning: LFLAGS is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Octave, use LDFLAGS instead
sh: line 1: gfortran: command not found`

Comment: Well I'd say the `gfortran: command not found` is the critical error here.  Some aspect of this project is written in Fortran so you need to install a Fortran compiler on your system, such as GNU Fortran.

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you so much sir. I installed fortran(gcc-fortran for arch) and it successfully ran my code.

Answer (score 1):

I am running arch and i had make installed turns out the issue was fortran so I simply diid `yay -S gcc-fortran` and installed fortran. This solved it for me